# MySQL installer for MySQL 5.7.18 on Windows 7 stuck

Tags: mysql, installation, windows-7

I have a somewhat weird problem. While installing MySQL installer for MySQL 5.7.18 on Windows 7, I can not access any option from the side menu of the installer other than "Type and Networking".

In the attached image:
[image: MySQL installer configuration]
I can not access other options such as "Account and Roles", etc. All are disabled.

What is wrong, and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution here - [MySQL Bug #85973](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85973)

Before running the installation, change the windows text size to smaller = 100%

Answer (score 2):

Use Alt-N for Next, Alt-X for Execute and Alt-F for Finish. Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative option to the previous ones, is to Go

*Start-->All Programs-->MySQL-->MySQL Installer-Community -->MySQL Installer-Community*

And configure the server and the rest from there.